# how create azure machine learning scoring image using local package

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have pkl package saved in my azure devops repository

using below code it searches for package in workspace.
How to provide package saved in repository

```
 ws = Workspace.get(
         name=workspace_name,
         subscription_id=subscription_id,
        resource_group=resource_group,
        auth=cli_auth)

image_config = ContainerImage.image_configuration(
    execution_script="score.py",
    runtime="python-slim",
    conda_file="conda.yml",
    description="Image with ridge regression model",
    tags={"area": "ml", "type": "dev"},
)

image = Image.create(
    name=image_name,  models=[model], image_config=image_config, workspace=ws
)

image.wait_for_creation(show_output=True)

if image.creation_state != "Succeeded":
    raise Exception("Image creation status: {image.creation_state}")

print(
    "{}(v.{} [{}]) stored at {} with build log {}".format(
        image.name,
        image.version,
        image.creation_state,
        image.image_location,
        image.image_build_log_uri,
    )
)

# Writing the image details to /aml_config/image.json
image_json = {}
image_json["image_name"] = image.name
image_json["image_version"] = image.version
image_json["image_location"] = image.image_location
with open("aml_config/image.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(image_json, outfile)
```

I tried to provide path to models but its fails saying package not found

models = $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/package_model.pkl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register model:
Register a file or folder as a model by calling [Model.register()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py#register-workspace--model-path--model-name--tags-none--properties-none--description-none--datasets-none--model-framework-none--model-framework-version-none--child-paths-none-).

In addition to the content of the model file itself, your registered model will also store model metadata -- model description, tags, and framework information -- that will be useful when managing and deploying models in your workspace. Using tags, for instance, you can categorize your models and apply filters when listing models in your workspace.

```
model = Model.register(workspace=ws,
                       model_name='',                # Name of the registered model in your workspace.
                       model_path='',  # Local file to upload and register as a model.
                       model_framework=Model.Framework.SCIKITLEARN,  # Framework used to create the model.
                       model_framework_version=sklearn.__version__,  # Version of scikit-learn used to create the model.
                       sample_input_dataset=input_dataset,
                       sample_output_dataset=output_dataset,
                       resource_configuration=ResourceConfiguration(cpu=1, memory_in_gb=0.5),
                       description='Ridge regression model to predict diabetes progression.',
                       tags={'area': 'diabetes', 'type': 'regression'})

print('Name:', model.name)
print('Version:', model.version)
```

Deploy machine learning models to Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-and-where?tabs=python

To Troubleshooting remote model deployment Please follow the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-troubleshoot-deployment?tabs=azcli#function-fails-get_model_path).

[image]